# How does my ISP DNS server contact the root DNS server?

Tags: dns, ip

From what I understood when my computer performs a DNS request it does the following:

Firstly my computer send a DNS request to its default dns server (my ISP DNS in my case).
Then my ISP DNS server send a request to a "root node DNS server".
My question is in that last point.

- How does the ISP DNS server contact te root node (with an IP ? (I heard that DNS root node IPs where secret (in order to avoid attacks / spamming))).
- Which port is used by the root node DNS
- Can I contact directly from my computer the root DNS ? (if yes how ?)

Thank you very much !

Comment: [The root mame servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server) are not secret, otherwise the wole system would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Each recursive nameserver in the world ships with a preconfigured root zone with the list of root nameservers and their IPv4+IPv6 addresses.
By a process called "priming" on start, each recursive nameserver will connect one of these to query for the current list, so that it can update its list of root servers.

All of that is not hidden in any way because otherwise the DNS does not work.

Every nameserver (recursive or authoritative) uses port 53, for both UDP and TCP queries.

You can of course contact directly the root nameservers but based on your questions I believe you have a misconception on what purpose this may have.
The DNS is a tree, if you contact a root nameserver it will only be able to reply with data about the level just below it, that is the list of TLDs, and you will not get data there about domains further down the tree.

Some examples:

### Getting list of current root nameservers

```
$ dig . NS

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> . NS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62572
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: c0ea66cf097962ab
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.          IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 40

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62572
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 27

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.          IN NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
.           264162 IN NS a.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS d.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS m.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS j.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS e.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS f.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS l.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS k.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS g.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS h.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS b.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS i.root-servers.net.
.           264162 IN NS c.root-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.root-servers.net. 600270 IN A 198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:503:ba3e::2:30
b.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 199.9.14.201
b.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:200::b
c.root-servers.net. 600270 IN A 192.33.4.12
c.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:2::c
d.root-servers.net. 600269 IN A 199.7.91.13
d.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:2d::d
e.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 192.203.230.10
e.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:a8::e
f.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:2f::f
g.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 192.112.36.4
g.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:12::d0d
h.root-servers.net. 600270 IN A 198.97.190.53
h.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:1::53
i.root-servers.net. 600270 IN A 192.36.148.17
i.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:7fe::53
j.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 192.58.128.30
j.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:503:c27::2:30
k.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 193.0.14.129
k.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:7fd::1
l.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 199.7.83.42
l.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:500:9f::42
m.root-servers.net. 600268 IN A 202.12.27.33
m.root-servers.net. 168267 IN AAAA 2001:dc3::35

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.10.229#53(192.168.10.229)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 29 10:19:08 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 811
```

### Asking a root nameserver about data for a TLD (yes, `red` is a TLD)

```
$ dig @g.root-servers.net red. NS +nocookie

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @g.root-servers.net red. NS +nocookie
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18270
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;red.           IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 32

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18270
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;red.           IN NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
red.            172800 IN NS b0.nic.red.
red.            172800 IN NS c0.nic.red.
red.            172800 IN NS a2.nic.red.
red.            172800 IN NS a0.nic.red.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a0.nic.red.     172800 IN A 65.22.36.25
a2.nic.red.     172800 IN A 65.22.39.25
b0.nic.red.     172800 IN A 65.22.37.25
c0.nic.red.     172800 IN A 65.22.38.25
a0.nic.red.     172800 IN AAAA 2a01:8840:26::25
a2.nic.red.     172800 IN AAAA 2a01:8840:29::25
b0.nic.red.     172800 IN AAAA 2a01:8840:27::25
c0.nic.red.     172800 IN AAAA 2a01:8840:28::25

;; Query time: 104 msec
;; SERVER: 192.112.36.4#53(192.112.36.4)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 29 10:20:35 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 280
```

## Asking a root nameserver for anything else down the tree (no direct reply as expected, just data to contact other nameservers for further recursive queries)

```
$ dig @g.root-servers.net www.stackoverflow.com. NS +nocookie

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @g.root-servers.net www.stackoverflow.com. NS +nocookie
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8649
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackoverflow.com. IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 50

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8649
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 27
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.stackoverflow.com. IN NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            172800 IN NS j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800 IN NS h.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.5.6.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.33.14.30
c.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.26.92.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.31.80.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.12.94.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.35.51.30
g.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.42.93.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.54.112.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.43.172.30
j.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.48.79.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.52.178.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.41.162.30
m.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN A 192.55.83.30
a.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:503:a83e::2:30
b.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:503:231d::2:30
c.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:503:83eb::30
d.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:500:856e::30
e.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:502:1ca1::30
f.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:503:d414::30
g.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:503:eea3::30
h.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:502:8cc::30
i.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:503:39c1::30
j.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:502:7094::30
k.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:503:d2d::30
l.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:500:d937::30
m.gtld-servers.net. 172800 IN AAAA 2001:501:b1f9::30

;; Query time: 105 msec
;; SERVER: 192.112.36.4#53(192.112.36.4)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 29 10:21:50 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 846
```

Comment: OK thank you very much for your answer. I still have a question. If the 13 IPs of the root DNS are public. Then how do the root DNS protect themselves from DDOS or other massive attack ?

Comment: Each IP is anycasted and at the end you have in fact more than 900 locations. The structures handling them also have huge pipes behing each one. And DDOS them gains nothing has it has been proved in the past: they only have the list of TLDs, and this is heavily cached everywhere. You can loose few of them completely without any user feeling a difference in its day to day browsing or email activities. Have a look at http://www.root-servers.org/ for many details and educational materials.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your time and your detailed answers.